# iPhone: Advanced Microphone Recorder APIs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I am building an App that allows our customers to record, save, and play recorded sound as a basic functionality. This should be straight using [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) Framework. What I also allow users are

1. Fast Forward and Reverse functionality.
2. User should also able to manipulate the sound. I mean they allow to insert the sound in between their recorded sound later.

Could anyone please tell me how could I achieve these? Is there any good open-source library for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AVAudioPlayer` supports manipulating the playback speed via the `rate` and `enableRate` properties, but it only allows forward playing.

The `MPMoviePlayerController` conforms to the [MPMediaPlayback](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback) protocol which allows you to specify any rate (even reverse).  Though this method will result in choppy audio for some rates.

As far as merging audio files, I think your best bet is to convert your samples to linear PCM. Then you can insert additional samples anywhere in your stream.

Comment: Hi Griz, I couldn't get this working. Please could you share any sample code for converting samples to linear PCM and edit it? Thanks.